# Is there a way do to a Kubernetes rollout and only wait on a subset of replicas?

Tags: gitlab-ci, kubectl

We are using the GitLab CI pipeline, and we deploy to Kubernetes with these commands:

```bash
kubectl set image deployment/our-app-name new-image:new-tag
kubectl rollout status deployment/our-app-name
```

At this point, kubectl waits for all 5 new replicas to start up, and all 5 old replicas to tear down. Sometimes this takes longer than others and then it times out. The specific error message is:

```
error: deployment "our-app-name" exceeded its progress deadline
```

Now, obviously I could brute force this using the `-timeout` argument, but I'm trying to avoid doing that. I'm hoping for guidance on optimizing this operation.

My first thought is to not have the pipeline wait for all the replicas to do their thing. If we could only wait on, say, 2 or 3 replicas to start, therefore we would know the app is capable of being deployed, and then have the pipeline effectively succeed while leaving Kubernetes to spin up the rest of the replicas, that would be great.

Comment: are you ok with `kubectl get po -l app.kubernetes.io/instance=whatever | jq -r '[.items[]|select(.status.phase == "Running")]|length'` type deal, or are you asking for how to do that exclusively using `kubectl`? I _believe_ `-o go-template=` will do it using only kubectl, but it will be incredibly chatty, as go-template is wont to be

Comment: How about if your initial deployment only has one replica, and after the rollout completes, you do a "kubectl scale" to the desired number of replicas?

Comment: Would that mean removing the replica information from the deployment file and then simply relying on a manual scale command post-deployment as part of the pipeline?